# Use SASS-Variables of Bootstrap in React components

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, next.js

I use Bootstrap with `SASS` in my React (Next.js) project. I would now like to use the `SASS` variables of Bootstrap in the SASS modules (scoped) of the components.

**/styles/style.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
```

**/pages/_app.tsx**

```
import '../styles/style.scss'
```

**/components/text/style.module.scss**

```
.text {
    font-size: $font-size-lg;
}
```

Of course, I now get an error because `$font-size-lg` was not defined.

How do I provide the bootstrap variables in the module files so I can use them?

Comment: As a sidenote: Bootstrap 5 exports most (if not all) of its scss variables into CSS variables prefixed by `--bs` so one could do `font-size: var(--bs-font-size-lg);` (I think bootstrap 4 did this unprefixed and to a lesser degree but I may be mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

##### What is the problem ?

You are importing the `Bootstrap SASS variables file` in your global `style.scss` file. However, `the SASS modules` (scoped) of your React components are not aware of the `variables` defined in the `global file`.

---

##### Solution

One way to make the variables available in your SASS modules is to define them again in the module files, this way you'll have to import the variables file in every SASS file.

To avoid importing variables file in every SASS file is by defining them globally in a way that they are shared among all the SASS files. You can do this by using the CSS `:export` directive.

For example, in your `style.scss` file, you can define the variables using the `:export` directive:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
:export {
  font-size-lg: $font-size-lg;
  // other variables
}
```

Then in your SASS modules (scoped) of your React components, you can import these variables by using the `:import` directive:

```
:import {
  font-size-lg
} from '../styles/style.scss';

.text {
    font-size: font-size-lg;
}
```

---

##### Extra

You can also use a library like [`sass-module-dts-generator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-module-dts-generator) that will generate a typeScript file with all the exported variables, this way you'll be able to use them in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the "[How to Use Sass with CSS Modules in Next.js](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-sass-with-css-modules-in-next-js/)" guide at freecodeCamp and it seems that you should import the `bootstrap variables` directly in your `scss` module.

Will it not work, if you import your `/styles/style.scss` in the `/components/text/style.module.scss` with the following import command?

```
@import "../../styles/style.scss"
```

Unfortunately, I cannot check it myself.

Comment: I actually already had the idea, but I would be reluctant to import the variables file into every SCSS file. Is there any way that the bundler could possibly provide the variables file automatically, as is the case with Nuxt.js?